# How can I know a JitsiMeetActivity is left?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am trying to implement this scenario: A user receives a Jitsi Conference Call request. After accepting the request, the room name is passed to the user and a new `JitsiMeetActivity` is launched. The code works until here. I am able to join in on a conversation. Now the thing I want to do is, after joining a conference call if the user wants to leave the call then another activity should start. If I can know when the user leaves the call I can do this.

If a method or some sort like `JitsiMeetActivity.isActive()` exists, it would be helpful.

The code:

```
if (room_name.length() > 0) {
            JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options
                    = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                    .setRoom(room_name)
                    .build();

            JitsiMeetActivity.launch(this, options);
        }
        
        //Now if the call ends
        Intent ac = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
        startActivity(ac);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new activity and implementing `JitsiMeetActivityInterface`, `JitsiMeetViewListener` from it. Thus, whenever I want to end a conference, I have access to `onConferenceTerminated` method.